# Calendar icon not opening the calendar in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I want to open my calendar from both 1. on clicking the textbox and 2. on clicking the calendar Icon

```
<div class="form-group">
      <div class='input-group'>
          <input type='text' class="form-control" datepicker-popup
              ng-model="model.start" is-open="opened.start" id='start'
              ng-click="opened.start = !opened.start" />
          <span class="input-group-addon" for='start' ng-click="opened.start = !opened.start">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
          </span>

     </div>
</div>
```

And controller code:

```
app.controller('dateCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
  $scope.model = {
    start: new Date('12/31/2014'),
    end: new Date()
  };

  $scope.opened ={
    start: false,
    end: false
  };
}]);
```

when I am clicking on the textbox it is working, but when I am clicking on calendar icon, nothing happening.

See the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/TRwUSQRzedkQji6uJ5js?p=preview).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use labels instead of spans, they are designed for this purpose. Just make sure to set up correct `for` and corresponding `id` attributes:

```
<div class='input-group'>
    <input type='text' class="form-control" datepicker-popup
        ng-model="model.start" is-open="opened.start" id='start'
        ng-click="opened.start = !opened.start" />
    <label class="input-group-addon" for='start'>
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
    </label>
</div>
```

Clicking on HTMLLabelElement generates click event on the related input field, so in this case you get intended behaviour.

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/xGPVMPPTOlzOhFIVdhG4?p=preview

**UPD.** Since you need toggle functionality, then in this case you indeed need javascript solution. Here we go, you need to prevent event bubbling, because Angular listens for events on the document level and closed calendar immediately:

```
<span class="input-group-addon" ng-click="opened.start = !opened.start; $event.stopPropagation()">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
</span>
```

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/CmJK1M0icGpKvd38S9mK?p=preview

Comment: I notice you changed the `span` to `label` and it is opening but on next click it is not closing

Comment: Oh, I should have mentioned that you want toggle behaviour. Then you indeed need a little javascript here.

Comment: It don't thing so, because I am toggling the open state on clicking the button, which is working for the textbox, thanks for your quick reply

Comment: Take a look at toggle variant with ngClick and explanation.